# AWS EC2 load balancer rule to redirect if query parameter is missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, query-string

Is there a way/syntax to redirect calls with an AWS ELB rule if a certain query parameter is missing?

I couldn't find anything related to empty query parameters in the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#query-string-conditions.

My use case would be to redirect back to app front page if e.g. query param `id` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wildcard `*` to match all values. Hence, you can configure a rule with `id` query string and `*` as value, to catch requests with `id` parameter.

Then in the default route, forward to your app front page.

Comment: Thanks, we have static assets under the same root path so this method wasn't viable. I was looking for a way to specifically say "when path is this and if this exact query param is missing go here", but decided to let the web app handle that case.